# I am trying to get the questions in a quiz to be asked in a random order with limited sucess

Tags: python

```
print("Transferring you to the quiz...")
print("Rules: ")
print("This quiz features questions about online safety. The questions are multiple choice so enter the number which corresponds to your answer. For every question you get right you will get a point. Good luck!")

score = 0
goes = 0

questions = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

import random
from random import shuffle
random.shuffle(questions)

print(questions)


if questions == 0:
    questions.remove(0)

q1 = input("What is CEOP? 1.Child Exploitation and Online Protection 2.Criminal Exploration and Online Protection 3.Child Exploitation and Organised Protectors: ")
if q1 == "1":
    print("That's right, well done!")
    score = score + 1
    goes = goes + 1
else:   
    print("That's wrong, unlucky!")
    goes = goes + 1

elif questions == 1:
    questions.remove(1)
    q2 = input("When you get an email from someone you do not know, what should you do? 1.Reply and say hello 2.Forward to your friends 3.Delete it and mark as spam: ")
    if q2 == "3":
        print("That's right, well done!")
        score = score + 1
        goes = goes + 1
    else:
        print("That's wrong, unlucky!")
        goes = goes + 1

elif questions == 2:
    questions.remove(2)
    q3 = input("How secret should you keep your passwords? 1.Give them only to your best friends 2.Never give out passwords except to your parents 3.Give them to strangers: ")
if q3 == "2":
    print("That's right, well done!")
    score = score + 1
    goes = goes + 1
else:
    print("That's wrong, unlucky!")
    goes = goes + 1

elif questions == 3:
    questions.remove(3)
    q4 = input("When an online contact who frightens you asks to meet you in person what should you do? 1.Arrange to meet them 2.Arrange to meet them with your best friend 3.Report to CEOP: ")
if q4 == "3":
    print("That's right, well done!")
    score = score + 1
    goes = goes + 1
else:
   print("That's wrong, unlucky!")
   goes = goes + 1

    elif questions == 4:
    questions.remove(4)
q5 = input("If an email asks you to enter your bank account details because of a problem with your account what should you do? 1.Contact the bank to check if they sent the email 2.Reply to the email 3.Enter your bank account details: ")
if q5 == "1":
print("That's right, well done!")
    score = score + 1
    goes = goes + 1
else:
    print("That's wrong, unlucky!")
    goes = goes + 1

while goes == 5:        
    print("End of quiz")
    print("Well done, your score was {0}".format(score))
    break
```

I am trying to get the questions of the quiz to be asked in a random order. I have shuffled the questions but after printing the random list the quiz stops...
I know some of the indenting is not correct but it is in my code...

Comment: the lines `if questions == 0:
    questions.remove(0)` are going to give you problems, since you are asking if a list equals an integer. In fact, all of your boolean tests with the for `if questions == <int>` are going to fail...

Comment: What you should be doing is asking `if questions[0] == "0": remove("0")` since you used strings for your random list of identifiers, not integers.

Answer (score 1):

You should have used dictionary here. Dictionary already contains elements in random order.

```
dict = {"question1": "ans1", "question2": "ans2", "question3": "ans3"}
for s in dict.keys():
  ans = raw_input(s)
  if ans == dict[s]:
    print "success"
  else:
    print "failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a list containing tuples:

```
list= [("myQuestion","answer"),("question2", "answer2")]
```

I would then shuffle it:

```
random.shuffle(list)
```

lastly, I would iterate over it:

```
for i in list:
    answer = input(i[0])
    if answer == i[1]:
        print "succes"
```

Let me know if this helps or mark the question as resolved ;)